# Cannot access value of a json object ? Cannot read property 'company_about' of undefined ?

Tags: json, reactjs, typescript

This is my JSON

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "job_id": 1,
    "company_profile": "Sales and Marketing",
    "company_about": "Established in 1992 , it is a renouned marketing company",
    "company_product": "Ford,Mustang,Beetle",
    "key_skills": "commmunication,english,spanish,german",
    "qualification": "High School,Masters",
    "job_description": "Must be a Local of Mumbai",
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null
}
```

]

I am trying to get its values.
this is my react code to log them.

```
 public getJobDetails = (jobid: number) => {
const JobId = jobid;
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/jobs/detail/' + JobId)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(
    responseJson => {
      console.log(responseJson);
      this.setState({ details: responseJson });
    },
    () => {
      console.log(this.state.details);
    }
  )
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });


 }

      public render() {
        const { details } = this.state;
        console.log(details);
        console.log(details[0]);
```

The console.log(details[0]) returns

```
{id: 1, job_id: 1, company_profile: "Sales and Marketing", company_about: "Established in 1992 , it is a renouned marketing company", company_product: "Ford,Mustang,Beetle", …}
```

But why does console.log(details[0].company_profile) return undefined???
The Error it gives is :

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'company_about' of undefined

can anyone help??

Comment: see if state is already populated when you are trying to access some complex objects. e.g. during first `render` this.state.details maybe be `undefined`, thus this error.

Comment: yes during first render it is undefined ? but later on it becomes defined?? still i am getting this error.

Comment: also add some meaningful strings to your `console.logs` and see how it renders.

Comment: i tried with JSON.stringify , but still undefined :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a conditional statement in your render so that if your request isn't complete and your state doesn't have details yet it doesn't load anything.

Edit --- Sample Code (not your application, but concept of what I mean)

import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';

```
export class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = { 
      data: [],
      isLoading: true
     }
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    this.fetchDetails()
  }

   fetchDetails = () =>{
     fetch('/some/url')
     .then(res => res.json())
     .then( => {
       this.setState({data, isLoading: false})
     })
   }


  render() { 
    return ( 
      <Fragment>
        {!this.state.isLoading && <ChildComponent data={this.state.data}} />}
      </Fragment>
     );
  }
}
```

Comment: You should add a code example here for the OP's benefit.

Comment: Yep  , man exactly - now working :) i just checked if(details[0] !== undefined){ console.log(details[0].company_about) } then it gave me the result :)

Comment: example would be : check for `details` to be truthy, then `details[0]`, then return `details[0].company_profile` can be expressed as `details && details[0] && details[0].company_about`.

Comment: Thanks a lot amigo , u saved me some more cups of coffee for the day :)

Comment: Added some sample code to show how I load my parent containers data and then pass it into children.

Answer (score 0):

Your fetch code is asynchronous and you don't have a default value set for `this.state` You can try a couple different options. You could redefine getJobDetails to return the promise rather than changing the state:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

     public getJobDetails = (jobid: number) => {
        const JobId = jobid;
        return fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/jobs/detail/' + JobId)
     }

     public render() {
         this.getJobDetails().then(response => {console.log(response[0])})
     }
}
```

Or you can set a default state

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    public state = {
        details: [...]
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Performing a network request every render cycle is not very efficient, so it's probably not the best route to go. I also forgot a third option, conditional rendering like this:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    state = { loading: true }
    getJobDetails = (jobid: number) => {
        fetch(...).then((response) => {
            this.setState({details: response})
            this.setState({loading : false})
        })
    } 
    render() {
        return this.state.loading ? <h1>Loading...</h1> : <div>{this.state.deatils}</div>
    }
}
```

Also you should not be converting your data to JSON if you want to access it as an Object

Comment: 1. Will this code `public render() {
         this.getJobDetails().then(response => {console.log(response[0])})
     }` run during each render? 2. Does React know how to handle promises inside `render`?

Comment: Render is just like any other function, and you can do any javascript you want in it, provided you return a react element or null. It will to the request every render so it may not be the most efficient. You can provide a default state, or a conditional render like loading for instance. I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

Try more logging, e.g.:

```
public getJobDetails = (jobid: number) => {
const JobId = jobid;
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/jobs/detail/' + JobId)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(
    responseJson => {
      console.log(`Fetch resulted in ${JSON.stringify(responseJson)}`);
      this.setState({ details: responseJson });
    },
    () => {
      // This line is supposed to act as error handler, but there is no error handling
// See this - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#Syntax

      console.log(this.state.details);
    }
  )
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(`Fetch resulted in error ${JSON.stringify(error)}`);
  });


 }

      public render() {
        const { details } = this.state;
        console.log('Rendering...'); 
        console.log(`step 1. ${JSON.stringify(details)}`);
// let's see if details are not undefined and try next level
        details && console.log(`step 2. ${JSON.stringify(details[0])}`);
```